# Redis and linked hashes

Tags: indexing, hash, redis, nosql

everyone

I would like to ask community of help to find a way of how to cache our huge plain table by splitting it to the multiple hashes or otherwise.

The sample of table, as an example for structure:

```
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  X1
A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  X2
A7  B5  C2  D1  E2  X3
A8  B1  C1  D1  E2  X4
A1  B6  C3  D2  E2  X5
A1  B1  C1  D2  E1  X6
```

This our denormalized data, we don't have any ability to normalize it.
So currently we must perform 'group by' to get required items, for instance to get all D* we perform 'data.GroupBy(A1).GroupBy(B1).GroupBy(C1)' and it takes a lot of time.

Temporarily we had found workaround for this by creating composite a string key:

```
A1 -> 'list of lines begin A1'
A1:B1 -> 'list of lines begin A1:B1'
A1:B1:C1 -> 'list of lines begin A1:B1:C1'
...
```

as a cache of results of grouping operations.

The question is how it can be stored efficiently?

Estimated number of lines in denormalized data around 10M records and as in my an example there is 6 columns it will be 60M entries in hash. So, I'm looking an approach to lookup values in O(N) if it's possible.

Thanks.

Comment: is the order always A->B->C....? Can the order be shuffled, like groupBy(B).groupBy(D).groupBy(A)... etc ?

Comment: Another question is what is the range of the index of each column? e.g What is the max value of i in A[i]/B[i]/C[i] etc

Comment: Order A->B->C, like as Country->State->County->etc.

Comment: For A it's around of 2000, for B it's around of 20000, but when the number will always lower then B. And we always have only 7 columns.